# I want to Use Both Tab Bar And Navigation Bar in Same View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I had Take ViewController And Put Navigation Controller from Object Library than Put Tab Bar Same As Navigation Controller....
But Tab Bar Can't Show In Controller...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First declare your tab bar controller in your delegate .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

then declare your root view controller and add it to navigation controller in .m file

```
UIViewController *homeViewController = [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navigationcontroller = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController] autorelease];
```

then add the array of controllers to tab bar

```
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationcontroller,secondViewController and so on, nil];
```